# Calculate Mean by Groupby, drop some rows with Boolean conditions and then save the file in original format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data like this.

[image]

I calculate the mean of each IDs

```
df.groupby(['ID'], as_index= False)['A'].mean()
```

Now, I want to drop all those Ids whose mean value is more than 3

```
df.drop(df[df.A > 3].index)
```

And this is here i am stucked. I want to save the file but in original format (without grouping and no mean value) and without those Ids whose means were more than 3.
Any Idea How can i achieve this. Output something like this. Also I want to know how many unique Ids were removed while using drop.

[image]

Comment: yea, Sorry I think I made mistake in that question, thatswhy i deleted. But thanks and I will post again if i get confused :)

Comment: That's exactly what i forget to put it there. that's why i deleted that questions, I have column called Value and that value is the one which needs to be re-sampled based on DateTime (1hr and weekly). I will edit that question again and re-post it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`, so is possible filtering by changed condition from `> 3` to `<=3` by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('ID')['A'].transform('mean') <= 3]
print (df1)

   ID  A
0   1  2
1   1  3
2   1  1
6   3  6
7   3  1
8   3  1
9   3  1
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID')['A'].transform('mean'))

0    2.000000
1    2.000000
2    2.000000
3    6.666667
4    6.666667
5    6.666667
6    2.250000
7    2.250000
8    2.250000
9    2.250000
Name: A, dtype: float64

print (df.groupby('ID')['A'].transform('mean') <= 3)

0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Seriously, you are amazing. Thanks a lot. I wish I could vote it unlimited times. It worked :)

Comment: @user3280146 - You are welcome! Btw, small advice - [don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: actually that wasnt images of code, it was just a code formatted.

Comment: @user3280146 - yes, worse is block of code, you are right.

Comment: After reading that link I understand what you meant. I will definitely keep that in my mind for future posting :)

Comment: @user3280146 - Ya, because sometiomes happens yoour question will be downvoted because it.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `groupby` and `filter`.  This solutions is a slower than using transform with boolean indexing.

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: x['A'].mean() < 3)
```

Output:

```
   ID  A
0   1  2
1   1  3
2   1  1
6   3  6
7   3  1
8   3  1
9   3  1
```